# Google App Engine (python): TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements with five words should end in 'reversed'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

This is using the web app framework, not Django.

The following template code is giving me an **TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements with five words should end in 'reversed'** error when I try to render a dictionary. I don't understand what's causing this error. Could somebody shed some light on it for me?

```
{% for code, name in charts.items %}
   <option value="{{code}}">{{name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm rendering it using the following:

```
class GenerateChart(basewebview):

    def get(self):
        values = {"datepicker":True}
        values["charts"] = {"p3": "3D Pie Chart", "p": "Segmented Pied Chart"}
        self.render_page("generatechart.html", values)

class basewebview(webapp.RequestHandler):
    ''' Base class for all webapp.RequestHandler type classes '''
    def render_page(self, filename, template_values=dict()):
        filename = "%s/%s" % (_template_dir, filename)
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This is using the web app framework,
>   not Django.

But framework apart, you must be using Django's templating -- and apparently in an old version, which does not support the "automatic unpacking" style of `for` -- probably the [0.96](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/#for) version that's the default for App Engine.  To use any part of more modern Django (including "just the templates") you must have a `settings.py` file and do:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
```

as per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django).  After that you can `from django import template` and you'll be using the 1.1 version of Django's templating engine.

Comment: Martellipedia does it again! Thanks.