# django- accessing items in a python dictionary

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

My dictionary is as follows:

```
data={"BE1234":"abc", "BA3212":"efg", etc}
```

I call it through django templates. According to the online manual, they say "if your context contained a dictionary `data`, the following would display the keys and values of the dictionary":

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the error:
TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements with five words should end in 'reversed': for key, value in data.items

Can anyone help me fix this error? It's really frustrating. Just wondering if I'm doing something stupid. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I've "upgraded" to django 1.3 and no longer get the error message. However, I still don't get the key//value either.

Comment: can you rename the dictionary name(items) and try

Comment: getting the same error when I try {% for key, value in items %} with the dictionary named items :(

Comment: This question in SO might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563365/google-app-engine-python-templatesyntaxerror-for-statements-with-five-word

Comment: Which version of django are you using?  This doesn't work for really old versions

Comment: For really old versions use something like{% for item in data.items %}
{{ item.0 }}: {{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: I got an error message when I tried what that link said: django 1.1 was requested, but 1.3.1.final.0 is already in use

Comment: also, when I just call the key {{BE1234}}, I'm able to get the value "abc".

Comment: I think I'm running django .96 actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you pass `data` as the context and not part of the context?

try passing this as the context:

```
data={"BE1234":"abc", "BA3212":"efg", etc}
context = {'data': data}
```

Comment: Thanks again...I was working on a roundabout hack for the problem - manipulating innerHTML text though javascript with regular expressions. Saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you wrote data.items instead of data.iteritems